# Repeated AJAX requests to Node server throttling (Express/jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new to Node.js and I'm doing the usual noob stuff with it to see how it works.

I have a client webpage with a button that performs a simple AJAX GET request with jQuery to a local Node server (the data is irrelevant), which in tur does an `app.get()` in which the value of a counter of every request is logged to the console, so that I can see how many of the requests were successful.

If I click on the button, say, once per second, the console shows the counter as it is supposed to. But if I *repeatedly* click on it (let's say 4 or 5 times per second), the server logs and shows the counter on the console much later, usually several minutes depending on the number of clicks. It's throttling the requests.

In terms of real production, it's unlikely the actual app I'm intended to make is going to "abuse" the AJAX requests like that, but I was expecting this were not an issue and I obviously can't rely on the user not abuse the button.

Here's a MWE that hopefully will replicate the problem.

**server.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
//const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
const app = express();
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var db;
var clientURL  = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydatabase'
var clientPort = 3000

MongoClient.connect(clientURL, (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  db = database
  app.listen(clientPort, () => {
    console.log('Listening on '+clientPort)
  })
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('client.ejs')
  })
})

var c = 0; // counter
app.get('/mydatabase/endpoint', (req, res) => {
  c = c + 1
  console.log(c)
})
```

**scripts.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(".button").on("click", function(){
        // AJAX GET
        $.ajax({
            url: "mydatabase/endpoint",
            type: "get",
            data: "..." // not imporant
        })
    });
})
```

The client is a simple HTML page with a `button` element that has a `.button` class.

PC specs: Windows 7 Professional 32 bit, Intel Core 2 Quad CPU Q6600 2.40GHz, 4GB RAM (a really old system, I know).

The question is why are requests throttling like that? Is it: a) my machine, b) a poor logic approach, or c) something to do with Express or Node.js? I don't remember this happening with, say, Apache/PHP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is going on here is that the browser is queuing requests once you exceed a certain qty.  Browsers limit the number of simultaneous requests they will make to any particular domain and when you exceed that, they queue the requests until a previous one returns.

And, because your `app.get()` with the counter does not return any response, the browser gets stuck waiting for the first N requests made by the browser to finish.  Eventually (several minutes later), they time out and then it can send more requests.

I rather doubt this is an issue with your server if all it is doing is logging a value.

You can probably make this issue disappear by just sending a response:

```
var c = 0; // counter
app.get('/mydatabase/endpoint', (req, res) => {
  ++c;
  console.log(c);
  res.send("" + c);
});
```

Remember that any route you define a handler for in Express SHOULD send some sort of response even if you have nothing to actually return.  Otherwise, the caller just sits there waiting for a response to happen and it can clog things up.

Comment: Alright, your explanation makes absolute sense. Sending a simple string as a response back to the client/browser did solve the issue. However, I could not send `c`, I got a 500 status because the app crashed.

Comment: @absay - OK, I changed my answer to send a string.  If this answers your question (which it sounds like it does), you can indicate that my clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.